# Property similar to subadditivity

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, terminology

A function is called [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity) such
that $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$ holds for any $x$, $y$ in the domain of $f$. (Let us say that, for example,
the domain is some subset of $\mathbb R$ closed under addition. Sometimes a more general case of functions on
$\mathbb R^n$ is studied.) Subadditive functions have many useful and interesting properties.

I am interested in the functions fulfilling stronger inequality
$$f(x+y) \le \max\{f(x),f(y)\}.$$

> - Is there a name for functions with the property?
> - Is there some book or survey paper describing basic properties of such functions, which you would recommend? Or are there at least some papers studying such functions?

Comment: Looks like norm in non-archimedian field (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)

Comment: Sounds related to Ultrametric(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space)

Comment: Sounds similar to [Quasiconvex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function). Who's next with a Wikipedia link? :) But seriously, the property simply says that every sublevel set $\{f(x)\le M\}$ is closed under addition. This is not the same as being convex, of course. Such a set will have to be either unbounded or $\{0\}$. Indeed, the function will look like a norm.